# How to remove unnecessary DevExpress VCL Components?

Tags: delphi

I am having one Delphi Project using [DevExpress VCL Components.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778037/how-to-reduce-devexpress-vcl-form-flickering)
The problem is that after compilation a lots of unnecessary components always added to the PE. If I remove those  unnecessary components using `PE Explorer` as show in the [image] Marked with Red Cross and some extra `Cursors`, the PE Runs flawlessly. So my question is **How to remove unnecessary DevExpress VCL Components in Compilation?**

Comment: Remove the units that define those form resources

Comment: Have you considered using the DevEx support forums for questions specific to their components?

Comment: Consider also turning off not using BPL's, like Skins. Btw, you have Skins with red cross in your screen sample.

Comment: @Zam What does "turning off not using BPLs" mean? How are runtime packages relevant?

Comment: CNPack Uses Cleaner?

http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=770&lang=en